# How to Print a Specific Value in an Array from a CSV File

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I imported my CSV File and made the data into an array. Now I was wondering, what can I do so that I'm able to print a specific value in the array? For instance if I wanted the value in the 2nd row, 2nd column. 
Also how would I go about adding the two values together?
Thanks.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
f = open("Test.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    print np.array(row)
f.close()
```

Comment: were you able to receive an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

col_position = 2
row_position = 2

f = open("Test.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for count_row, row in enumerate(csv_f):
   if count_row == row_position:
       print row[col_position]
   else:
       pass

f.close()
```

keep in mind that python python counts list positions starting with 0 and that your array is really a list of lists.  So if you want position (2,2) and assuming no header row, you should actually request (1,1) as (0,0) is the first element of the first list (row)

EDIT to address comment:
say you want to add elements a = (0,0) and b = (1,1) of your array:

```
import csv
col_a = 0
row_a = 0
col_b = 1
row_b = 1

f = open("Test.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for count_row, row in enumerate(csv_f):
   if count_row == row_a:
       a = row[col_a]
   else if count_row == row_b:
       b = row[col_b]
   else:
       pass

print int(a) + int(b)

f.close()
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Also what if I wanted to add two values in the array together? How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

To get specific values within your array/file, and add together:

```
import csv

f = open("Test.csv")
csv_f = list(csv.reader(f))

#returns the value in the second row, second column of your file
print csv_f[1][1]

#returns sum of two specific values (in this example, value of second row, second column and value of first row, first column
sum = int(csv_f[1][1]) + int(csv_f[0][0])
print sum
```